# Freetds could not connect to SQL Azure by server name (-S), but connect by host (-H) works

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, freetds

I have installed freetds and it looks working fine, when I try to connect by host:

```
tsql -H myhost -U myuser -P mypass -p 1433
locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

I have configured freetds.conf:

```
[azure]
        host = myhost
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

But when I'm trying to connect by server name (azure) it fails:

```
tsql -S azure -U myuser -P mypass
locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 40532 (severity 20, state 1) from azure:
    "Cannot open server "azure" requested by the login.  The login failed."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
```

Tried on macos and debian.

Answer (score 11):

The answer was simple, but strange. When you connect by config file (-S) you should use username@host as login, not just username. It's strange, but when you connect by host (-H), you could use only username (but could use username@host too).

Comment: Wow. That's _perfect._ It took me HOURS to get to this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Glad it worked out for you. Check out this doc - http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm

As general practice, we recommend that you use -S

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Link looks dead